# Which mod_rewrite rule can remove index.php and php extensions (from another existing rule)?

Tags: php, .htaccess, mod-rewrite

I use the following pattern:

```
http://example/index.php?lang=en
http://example/index.php?lang=es
http://example/index.php?lang=zh-tw
http://example/index.php?lang=zh-cn
```

And I use the following mod_write rule:

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteRule ^([a-z]{2}(-[A-Z]{2})?)/(.*) $3?lang=$1 [L,QSA]
```

With that rule I can use the following URLs which redirect me to the URLs above (the original ones):

```
http://example/en/index.php
http://example/es/index.php
http://example/zh-cn/index.php
http://example/zh-tw/index.php
```

I wish I could just type:

```
http://example/en
http://example/es
http://example/zh-cn
http://example/zh-tw
```

To access the index pages...

and type this:

```
http://example/en/thanks
http://example/es/thanks
http://example/zh-cn/thanks
http://example/zh-tw/thanks
```

to enter a `thanks.php` file I have.

Any suggestions to get that result?

(I think this should be quite common. Almost every professional website has pages in this fashion: example/section).

Comment: So you’re looking for a rule that does what?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I understood what you were looking for correctly, the following should do what you want (my rules make the assumption that you're using the root of a domain):

```
RewriteEngine on

# Go to index.php by default if nothing is specified after the language
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} ^/[a-z]{2}(-[A-Za-z]{2})?/?$
RewriteRule ([^/]*)/?$ index.php?lang=$1

# Rewrite domain.com/lang/index to domain.com/lang
RewriteRule ^([a-z]{2}(-[A-Z]{2})?)/index(\.php)?$ $1 [R,QSA]

# Allow pages to be specified without the .php extension
# The RewriteCond tells mod_rewrite to not rewrite if the request is a real file
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteRule ^([a-z]{2}(-[A-Z]{2})?)/(.*)(\.php)? $3.php?lang=$1 [L,QSA]
```

If you are not at the root of the domain (ie. your URLs are domain.com/subdomain/en/index), you need to specify `RewriteBase /subdomain` and modify your `RewriteCond` slightly (you'd put the rules in a .htaccess file in the subdirectory):

```
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} ^/subdomain/[a-z]{2}(-[A-Za-z]{2})?/?$
```

If you're still having trouble getting your CSS to load, try using absolute paths. The relative path will apply **after** the redirect.

Comment: @Daniel Vandersluis Thanks it almost worked but when I enter: http://alex-chen.net/test/en/thanks en, and es are displayed but with no CSS style and zh-tw and zh-cn can't be found!
(I used your code above just after my code I mention up there).

Comment: I updated my first rule to fix the issue you were having with zh-cn too.

Comment: @Daniel Vandersluis Weird, it works for alex-chen.net/en. But when you type alex-chen.net/en/thanks the page is shown with no CSS. Then if I use the code you provided: RewriteCond \.(css... it says internal server error.

Comment: Full htaccess: `RewriteEngine on

# Don't rewrite css, js, jpg or png files
 RewriteCond \.(css|js|jpe?g|png)$
 RewriteRule ^(.*)$ $1 [L,QSA])

# Go to index.php by default if nothing is specified after the language
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} ^/([a-z]{2}(-[A-Z]{2})?)/?$
RewriteRule ([a-z-]{2,4})/?$ index.php?lang=$1 [QSA]

# Rewrite domain.com/lang/index to domain.com/lang
RewriteRule ^([a-z]{2}(-[A-Z]{2})?)/index(\.php)? $1 [R,QSA]

# Allow pages to be specified without the .php extension
RewriteRule ^([a-z]{2}(-[A-Z]{2})?)/(.*)(\.php)? $3.php?lang=$1 [L,QSA]`

Comment: Probably better to paste a big block of code like that somewhere else, the formatting is not maintained as a comment. What is the full URL for your CSS file?

Comment: @Daniel Vandersluis Here it is: http://pastebin.com/KjTuxprn.

My CSS are in /styles and my Javascript in /scripts.

Comment: I've updated once again. The .htaccess as given works for me. As mentioned in my edit, you probably will want to make sure you use absolute paths for your CSS/JS.

Comment: @Daniel Vandersluis Sorry, how do I write the rule if my CSS are in /styles and Javascript in /scripts and pictures in /images? (I sued the onw in your first comment (comment number 2) but I says Internal Server Error. (Right now is commented)

Comment: I mean in your HTML: `<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="http://yourdomain.com/styles/style.css">`, etc.

Comment: @Daniel Vandersluis It is like this: <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="styles/global.css" />

Comment: Right, so just change `styles/global.css` to the full URL (`http://alex-chen.net/test/styles/global.css` or whatever)

Comment: @Daniel Vandersluis Weird I did this: <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="http://alex-chen.net/styles/global.css" />
and http://alex-chen.net/en/thanks still with no CSS nor Javscript.
(I deleted the /test folder, I'm not using it anymore).

Comment: @Daniel Vandersluis never mind now it works thanks! But is there a way of doing this without changing my /style path in my thanks.php file (which is in my root folder with index.php)?

Comment: You can set up a rule to redirect files ending in .css to /styles/$1 or something along those lines.